# GitHub: Bulk copy every repository in one organization to another organization

Tags: git, github

Let's say that I want to create a new organization "B" that should contain copies of every repository in organization "A".

So, how can I copy every repository in organization "A" to organization "B" automatically (not fork; they should appear as regular repositories)?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/

Comment: A fork is a copy, a transfer is a move, what exactly do you want to do here? Do you want to move the ownership, or make copies of the repositories? Your question is vague because you start by saying you want the second organization to get forks of ever repository, then in the next paragraph, you state that they should not be forks. So what is it? Please clarify what you want to be done here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I edited the post. Is it clear now?

Comment: Not sure there is an automated way to do this, but you could of course clone every repository down manually, then create new repositories on the new account and push your local clones up to the new accounts new repositories. You could probably script it, just provide a list of repositories.

Answer (score 5):

GitHub has a convenient command-line tool: `hub` found at https://hub.github.com

I've written an example to move all repos from all your organisations to `my_new_organisation_name`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

orgs="$(hub api '/user/orgs' | jq -r '.[] | .login')";
repos="$(for org in $orgs; do hub api '/orgs/'"$org"'/repos' | jq -r '.[] | .name';
         done)"

for org in $orgs; do
    for repo in $repos; do
        ( hub api '/repos/'"$org"'/'"$repo"'/transfer'
                  -F 'new_owner'='my_new_organisation_name' | jq . ) &
    done
done
```

For users rather than organisation, set `my_new_organisation_name` to the replacement username, remove the outer loop, and replace the `repos=` line with:

```bash
repos="$(hub api /users/SamuelMarks/repos | jq -r '.[] | .name')"
```

EDIT: Found a [GUI](https://github.com/floe/github-bulk-editor) if you prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54549899

Comment: I think this is not an official Github tool

Comment: Not the GUI but the CLI for sure

Comment: [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com) is an official tool from Github. But `hub` isn't (though some Github employees have contributed to it).

Comment: At the bottom of the website it says "made with <3 at GitHub"… EDIT: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/gh-vs-hub.md