# Bulk editor for Github repos?

Tags: github-api

I have a large number of private repositories in a Github org which I want to transfer to another org for archiving, and remove all teams in the process.

I already came across https://github.com/ahmadnassri/github-bulk-transfer, and I could of course also roll my own implementation with the libraries from https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/, but I'm honestly surprised that there is no sort of bulk editor for Github repos where you can execute API commands for a selected subset of repos.

Any hints welcome!

Comment: I could add that functionality to my Git-Captain project (or you can fork my project and implement it). If you are interested, add a feature request to the project in the issues section. It requires standing up a server to host the Node.js server, but I imagine it wouldn't be all that difficult, since I think I already have some of the structure to implement this. https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain

Comment: FTR, _none_ of the existing libraries for the Github API I've looked at (all the ones for Python at least) support the "Transfer repository" command. I'll probably take the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626326/838719 and just use requests + json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I *did* end up rolling my own, was pretty straightforward thanks to PyGTK, requests + json.

Result is up on Github: https://github.com/floe/github-bulk-editor, feedback welcome!

(Even though it only allows bulk transfer of repos, because that's what I needed right now, I've tried to keep the internals as generic as possible, so most other Github API commands should be very easy to add.)

Comment: That worked marvellous after `pip install PyGObject`. Thank you!