# Transfer all GitHub repositories from one user to another user

Tags: github

Is there a way to transfer all GitHub repositories owned by one user to another user? Is this functionality accessible by an admin (eg. on Enterprise, if the user can no longer access GitHub)?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub has a convenient command-line tool: `hub` found at https://hub.github.com

I've written an example to move all repos from all your organisations to `my_new_organisation_name`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

orgs="$(hub api '/user/orgs' | jq -r '.[] | .login')";
repos="$(for org in $orgs; do hub api '/orgs/'"$org"'/repos' | jq -r '.[] | .name';
         done)"

for org in $orgs; do
    for repo in $repos; do
        ( hub api '/repos/'"$org"'/'"$repo"'/transfer'
                  -F 'new_owner'='my_new_organisation_name' | jq . ) &
    done
done
```

For users rather than organisation, set `my_new_organisation_name` to the replacement username, remove the outer loop, and replace the `repos=` line with:

```bash
repos="$(hub api /users/SamuelMarks/repos | jq -r '.[] | .name')"
```

EDIT: Found a [GUI](https://github.com/floe/github-bulk-editor) if you prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54549899